# Cannot able to bind value with element that inside the innerhtml

Tags: html, angular

External html file that is loading form server:

```
<h1>Name {{name}}</h1>
```

In **sample.component.hmtl**:

```
<div class="htmldata" [innerHtml]="htmlData"> 
</div>
```

In **sample.component.ts**:

```
name: any = 'sample text'
// download file from server
 downloadFile() {
    this.http.get(this.fileUrl, { responseType: 'text' }).subscribe(res => {
      this.htmlData = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(res);
      console.log(this.htmlData);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To save your time: You **can't** bind a component attributes with an html given as a string to innerHtml.

You can find a more detailed answer: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41089093/9498818)